# Is a namespace the same thing as scope in C++?

Tags: c++

Is a namespace the same thing as scope in C++ programming language? Are these two words synonyms and can be used interchangably?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. A namespace is a kind of scope, but there are several kinds of scope that aren't namespaces. Some examples are:

- **block scope:** symbols (usually local variables) declared within a statement block enclosed in `{...}`;
- **function scope:** a function's outermost block scope;
- **class scope:** the members of a class.

Comment: +1; I think "block scope" includes several variants, like method scope, function scope, loop scope... - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b7kfh662(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Does block scope also include the statement immediately following a control-flow statement when there is not a set of curly braces?

Comment: As it happens, the "global scope" is a namespace ([basic.scope.namespace]/3).

Answer (score 2):

Not completely.

In C++, a scope is generally determined by pair of opening and closing braces: `{` and `}`, this includes:

- namespaces
- classes and structs
- functions and methods
- simple "blocks" within functions or methods

However there are a few exceptions, or specificities for a number of statements that may introduce variables that will live in the scope they immediately precede:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
  // i accessible here
}

while (int c = getchar()) {
  // c accessible here
}

try {
  // ...
} catch(std::exception const& e) {
  // e accessible here
}

void foo(int i) {
  // i accessible here
}
```

And there is the most surprising `if` statement:

```
if (int var = /**/)
{
  // var is accessible here
}
else
{
  // var is accessible here too!
}
```

Those scopes are a bit special :)

They also can degenerate in implicit scopes, because the C rules (that C++ also follows) make the `{` and `}` pair optional for the statements:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) std::cout << i << "\n";
// i no longer accessible here
```

There is also a scope for the template parameters: they are brought to life at their declaration point and live until the end of the class or function they were templating.

```
template <typename U>
void foo() {
} // U accessible up until this point
```

Finally, there is also the "most outer" scope, that is the global namespace, which is the "root" scope, in a way.

Comment: +1 for the most surprising `if` statement. Had seen this long before.

Comment: @Nawaz: I must admit I really like this possibility, as I always strive to give the tigher scope possible to my variables :)

Comment: That is why the declaration and its scope completely makes sense if the Standard allows this.

Answer (score 0):

No they are not.

A scope is pretty much similar to an object's lifetime - similar, not the same.

```
class A;

//....
{
   A a;  //begin scope for object a
}
//object a is out of scope
```

A namespace is a useful way to group declarations and definitions in C++.

You can name a namespace a scope, but a scope is much more than that. See the scope resolution operator: a method or variable can be part of a class scope and not in a namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia's articles on [Scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29) & [Variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_%28programming%29#Scope_and_extent) should be helpful.